# ngx-bootstrap tooltip in angular not working

Tags: angular, tooltip, ngx-bootstrap

Good day everyone, I am using ngx-bootstrap@9.0.0 in angular 14 and bootstrap 5 to display a tooltip but its not showing. Here is the HTML in the template file:

```
<td tooltip="Hi this is a term"><i>{{item.term}}</i></td>
```

I did everything according to the documentation [here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/tooltip?tab=overview)

I have imported the TooltipModule in the admin.module.ts as below;

```
import { TooltipModule } from "ngx-bootstrap/tooltip";
```

And I included it in the imports as below

```
imports: [...TooltipModule.forRoot(), PopoverModule.forRoot()]
```

I even uninstalled the package and reinstalled it but it did not work.

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "fiaschool-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^9.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.19",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

Please if any one has any idea why the tooltip is not displaying, help me out here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Pieterjan-I didn't get any error. It simply refuses to display.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div ngbTooltip="tooltip wording here" placement="bottom-end"  tooltipClass="optional_class">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).